# Show methods associated with a particular class

Tags: r, class, r-s4, r-s3

I'd like to see a list of all methods associated with a certain object class.  E.g. if I see that some model fit routine returns an object of class "foo", I'd like to know if the package (or any other package) have defined methods such as `simulate.foo`, `update.foo`, `coef.foo`, `print.foo` etc. How do I do this?

I know that `methods` solves the inverse problem (assuming an S3 class), but obviously I don't want to search through every object that has defined a `print` function in order to find out if my class of interest has one.  I've probably forgotten something very simple here.  thanks!

(Ideally it would be nice to see solutions for S3 and S4 classes).

**Update**: Ideally a solution should reveal methods that are hidden as well, just as the `methods` function does.  For instance, `methods("simulate")` shows:

```
> methods("simulate")
[1] simulate.lm*
```

so in a query for methods associated with the `lm` class, we would want to recover this simulate method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am I being a bonehead, or is `methods(class="foo")` what you want (for S3 methods)???

```
methods(class="lm")
##  [1] add1.lm*           alias.lm*          anova.lm           case.names.lm*    
##  [5] confint.lm*        cooks.distance.lm* deviance.lm*       dfbeta.lm*        
##  [9] dfbetas.lm*        drop1.lm*          dummy.coef.lm*     effects.lm*       
## [13] extractAIC.lm*     family.lm*         formula.lm*        hatvalues.lm      
## [17] influence.lm*      kappa.lm           labels.lm*         logLik.lm*        
## [21] model.frame.lm     model.matrix.lm    nobs.lm*           plot.lm           
## [25] predict.lm         print.lm           proj.lm*           qr.lm*            
## [29] residuals.lm       rstandard.lm       rstudent.lm        simulate.lm*      
## [33] summary.lm         variable.names.lm* vcov.lm*          
## 
##    Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

`showMethods` works for S4 classes (taken from @JoshO'Brien's now-deleted answer, for reference):

```
library(sp)
showMethods(classes="SpatialPolygons")

## Function: [ (package base)
## x="SpatialPolygons"
## 
## Function: addAttrToGeom (package sp)
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="data.frame"
## 
## Function: coerce (package methods)
## from="GridTopology", to="SpatialPolygons"
## from="SpatialGrid", to="SpatialPolygons"
## from="SpatialPixels", to="SpatialPolygons"
## from="SpatialPolygons", to="SpatialLines"
## from="SpatialPolygons", to="SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
## 
## Function: coordinates (package sp)
## obj="SpatialPolygons"
## 
## Function: coordnames (package sp)
## x="SpatialPolygons"
## 
## Function: coordnames<- (package sp)
## x="SpatialPolygons", value="character"
## 
## Function: over (package sp)
## x="SpatialGrid", y="SpatialPolygons"
## x="SpatialPoints", y="SpatialPolygons"
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialGrid"
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialGridDataFrame"
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialPoints"
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialPointsDataFrame"
## 
## Function: overlay (package sp)
## x="SpatialGridDataFrame", y="SpatialPolygons"
## x="SpatialGrid", y="SpatialPolygons"
## x="SpatialPointsDataFrame", y="SpatialPolygons"
## x="SpatialPoints", y="SpatialPolygons"
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialGrid"
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialPoints"
## 
## Function: plot (package graphics)
## x="SpatialPolygons", y="missing"
## 
## Function: polygons (package sp)
## obj="SpatialPolygons"
## 
## Function: polygons<- (package sp)
## object="data.frame", value="SpatialPolygons"
## 
## Function: recenter (package sp)
## obj="SpatialPolygons"
## 
## Function: spChFIDs (package sp)
## obj="SpatialPolygons", x="character"
## 
## Function: spsample (package sp)
## x="SpatialPolygons"
```

Comment: You beat me by 13 seconds :-)

Comment: Umm -- somebody was being boneheaded, but it wasn't you ;-)

Comment: Indeed! I knew there had to be a built-in function for that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using `.lm` as a regex pattern within `apropos` rather than searching fruitlessly for `.foo`:

```
> apropos("\\.lm")
 [1] "anova.lm"        "anova.lmlist"    "hatvalues.lm"    "kappa.lm"        "model.frame.lm"  "model.matrix.lm"
 [7] "panel.lmline"    "plot.lm"         "predict.lm"      "prepanel.lmline" "print.lm"        "residuals.lm"   
[13] "rstandard.lm"    "rstudent.lm"     "summary.lm"
```

There are also methods that begin with "lm." so you might want those as well:

```
> apropos("lm\\.")
 [1] ".__C__anova.glm.null" ".__C__glm.null"       "glm.control"          "glm.convert"         
 [5] "glm.fit"              "glm.nb"               "lm.fit"               "lm.fit.qr.bare"      
 [9] "lm.gls"               "lm.influence"         "lm.pfit"              "lm.ridge"            
[13] "lm.wfit"
```

And if you wanted leave out the "glm." methods use the somewhat more restricted regex:

```
> apropos("^lm\\.")
[1] "lm.fit"         "lm.fit.qr.bare" "lm.gls"         "lm.influence"   "lm.pfit"        "lm.ridge"      
[7] "lm.wfit"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears this will fail in cases where the class is not exported to the NAMESPACE, e.g. all methods that appear with an asterix * when listed by "methods()".

Answer (score 2):

For the S3 case, `methods` has an argument `class` for this:

```
> methods(class="lm")
 [1] add1.lm*           alias.lm*          anova.lm           case.names.lm*    
 [5] confint.lm*        cooks.distance.lm* deviance.lm*       dfbeta.lm*        
 [9] dfbetas.lm*        drop1.lm*          dummy.coef.lm*     effects.lm*       
[13] extractAIC.lm*     family.lm*         formula.lm*        hatvalues.lm      
[17] influence.lm*      kappa.lm           labels.lm*         logLik.lm*        
[21] model.frame.lm     model.matrix.lm    nobs.lm*           plot.lm           
[25] predict.lm         print.lm           proj.lm*           qr.lm*            
[29] residuals.lm       rstandard.lm       rstudent.lm        simulate.lm*      
[33] summary.lm         variable.names.lm* vcov.lm*
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Not quite sure how I forgot this, as I must've used it a hundred times ...